# error when adding Custome C# template, VS2010, new computer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, envdte

I have a custom template that I built in VS2010.  A new user who was able to successfully open this template previously, can not longer.  She did reimaged and VS2010 reinstalled.  Is there anything specific needed to add a new item based off a custom template to your project.  Other users are not reporting an issue so I know is something with her install. The error she gets is:

> **Unable to cast COM object of type 'System._ComObject' to class type 'EnvDTE.DTEClass'. COM components that enter the CLR and do not
>   support IProviderClassInfo of that do not have any interop assembly
>   registered will be wrapped in the _ComObject type.  Instances of this
>   type cannot be cast to any other class; however they can be cast to
>   interfaces as long as the underlying COM component support
>   QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.**

Any clue how to resolve.  I assume that since this works on every other computer, there is nothing in my code that needs to be fixed (maybe a message thrown to the user to explain this better) but this feels very environmental.

Thanks;

Comment: Complete reimage and reinstall of 2010?  Really?  Because it sounds like some unregistered VS native dlls.  Don't know what she should do to fix, other than 1) actually reinstalling visual studio 2) wiping her machine, installing from valid media, and reinstalling visual studio or (probably a better idea to try first) 3) install the visual studio 2010 SDK.

Comment: its a work computer so she had not choice but to get reimaged (business reasons beyond this issue). I will try the SDK as that seems the most invasive attempt.  Thanks... ill report back with success or failure.

Comment: installing the SDK did not work. However we did get an error saying VS2010 is not installed when we ran the SDK.  I looked in the Path and VS version 9 was in there but not 10, so I fixed that, still not good.  I needed to change a value in the registry to say that VS 2010 SP1 was installed.  That got us past the SDK install error, but original issue remains.

Comment: That's the root of the problem.  Someone is doing something out of the ordinary when installing Visual Studio.  I'm not sure *what*, but tell them to reimage and reinstall visual studio **accepting all defaults**.

Comment: OK that may be the next step.  I will see if we can do that.  Thanks for the tips and idea's